# Performing git rebase interactive from Java code

Tags: java, git, rebase, git-rebase

When using `git rebase --interactive` from command line you got the list of commits in the terminal window then you modify them and save, at this moment the rebase process start then you can use `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue` to rewrite the history

I'm trying to automate rewriting the whole history from Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, in another thread I open and edit the todo file at `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo`

The problem is that the code stops at executing the rebase command

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("git rebase --continue --root $TIP");
```

as it is waiting the editor to stop, so what to do to overcome this problem and enforce the rebase process to start?

Answer (score 0):

When the rebase fails, the rebase will stop and indicate manual (interactive) items are required in order to move forwards.

Given that a git rebase-interactive is simply building up a sequence of commits, you can build up a list of commits and then invoke a series of `git cherry-pick sha` which is essentially what the interactive rebase is doing.